# Wirelessly mirror iPad screen to MacBook?

Tags: ipad, screen-sharing, mirroring

I've heard of the software ”Reflector" being able to do this. And I know I can also do this though screen sharing during a Zoom meeting. But I want to be able to do this natively, without having to pay for proprietary software, and without having to jump through the hoops of always having to set up a Zoom call.

What are my options?

Comment: What OS are you on? Can you explain exactly what you're trying to do? You want to have your iPad screen visible on your Mac, but not necessarily in a Zoom call?

Comment: @benwiggy Yes, that is correct. I want to see what I am doing on my iPad, as a separate window on my MacBook. I am a teacher, and my class likes it when I use my iPad/Noteablity to project my notes on the front broad. Right now I can only accomplish this by using Zoom to steam the iPad's display. But this require an internet connect (which is spotty in my school) and takes multiple extra steps to set up at the start of each class.

Comment: Any reason your notes can't be projected (how?) from a Mac directly?

Comment: My notes are hand written, in real time, on the iPad. The crux of the issue is that I can connect my MacBook to a projector-setup in the classroom, but I can’t find a way to project my iPad directly.

Answer (score 1):

MacOS has a feature called 'Sidecar', which allows an iPad to be used as a display for the Mac. But AFAIK this doesn't work the other way round.

In short: there is no such 'native' functionality, so you will need to use third-party software, some of which may well require payment for their efforts. Reflector is $20.